# SNAP a point onto a custom road netowork

Tags: python, python-3.x, routes, gps, reverse-geocoding

This is not a repeat question as I have some specific requirements. Please provide input wrt python.
I have a road network in the form of coordinates of nodes, that's is I have all Lat and Long of all routes of a city.

Now, I have a list of GPS coordinates ( a bus route ) and I want to match it to original route.

This is similar to Google roads API. I tried using reverse geocoder but I am able understand it..please help

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [osmnx](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx) package for python. You can create a bounding box of your latitude and longitude coordinates, retrieve the appropriate map data of this box and then snap the lat long coords to the closest nodes of the street network.

```
bounding_box = ((gps_df.longitude.min(), gps_df.longitude.max(),
                 gps_df.latitude.min(), gps_df.latitude.max()))

# Downloading the map as a graph object
g = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type='drive')

route = []

# get the nearest nodes to the locations
for i in range(len(lat_list)):
    node = ox.get_nearest_node(g, (lat_list[i], long_list[i]))
    route.append(node)

#flat the lists
edge_nodes = list(zip(route[:-1], route[1:]))
```